# Number of $n$ digit integers where digits appear an odd number of times

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, decimal-expansion

[Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178391/does-the-sum-of-reciprocal-of-the-numbers-which-digital-expansion-does-not-have) asked about the convergence of the sum of reciprocals of  integers where digits appear only an odd number of times.  (Digits which do not appear are ignored, so for example $14404$ is included since $1$ and $0$ appear once and $4$ appears three times.)

It would be possible to show that the sum of reciprocals diverges, using the number of $n$-digit integers  where digits appear an odd number of times.  For small $n$, the numbers of such integers appear to be

```
n  1  2   3    4     5      6       7        8        9        10         11          12
#  9 81 657 4860 33705 228096 1555857 10782720 75810825 543977856 3989477457 29758855680
```

and for large $n$

- about $\frac{10-1}{10 \times 2^{10-1}} \times 10^n$ for even $n$
- about $\frac{10-1}{ 2^{10-2}} \times (10-1)^n$ for odd $n$ (smaller because ten odd numbers cannot add up to an odd number)

These are empirical results.  Something similar seems to work in other bases, and replacing all the $10$s with $2$s leads to an easy proof.

I was wondering whether a proof was possible justifying this $\frac{10-1}{10 \times 2^{10-1}}$, or at least a lower bound for the multiplicative factor for even $n$.

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146548/number-of-strings-when-each-character-must-occur-even-times is a similar question which you might adapt

Comment: @Empy2 That looks useful - though the odd case likely to be more complicated since in your link zero occurrences can be used as an even number while here it is an ignored number

Comment: Choose your k digits, in how many ways, then do the generating function, then sum over k.